# Request for permission to access location trough SMS?

Tags: android, geolocation, notifications, sms

I'm trying to figure out how to request another Android device for permission to access its location. Maybe through some link on a SMS to launch Google latitude?

The point is it should be instantaneous, like a Notification or an SMS.

What would be the closest strategy you can think of?

UPDATE:

Thanks guys for all your answers. After considering them all I am still a bit confused about what strategy to adopt.

Probably is better to tell you what I'm trying to implement:

Someone is going to pick you up. You send him a request, he accepts and the app shows you how far away he is and how long it will take him to get to you.

I didn't want the receiver to be forced to have the app cause it would lower its use. I guess that requisite could be dismissed.

Sorry for the confussion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't want the receiving user to have to install an app, you could send an SMS with a link to a website you control that uses web geolocation APIs to report position: http://dev.w3.org/geo/api/spec-source.html

The user will need to click the link in the SMS, then they will be prompted to allow the page to access their location. This will work not only on Android devices, but on any device with a browser that supports these APIs

Answer (score 2):

It depends on how heavy duty your apps are.

If I were you I would write a system where the Apps would maintain a connection to a central server. That way your Apps can be notified the moment that anything happens. It could also be seamlessly integrated allowing your App (make sure you ask permission to allow it initially obviously) to send location data when requested without any interaction.

This is obviously more battery intensive for such a simple operation, but that is the best way to get instantaneous notifications.

Another way you could do it is to simply send an email to the recipient with a custom URL scheme.

Such as:

```
yourlocationapp://get.location/respond.to
```

You could parse that kind of URL in your App [by setting](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/data-element.html):

```
<data android:scheme="yourlocationapp" />
```

In your intent-filter.

This requires more in the way of user interaction though.

Comment: The problem is I'm trying to do it without the receiver having the same app as the sender. That's why I thought of Google Latitude working on the background for me? Would that be possible?

Comment: My final goal is to know how far away someone is from me without that someone having to install anything, and using that information on my app.

Comment: There are a few anti-patterns in this answer. Maintaining a connection to a server all the time will not be good for your users batteries at all, consider something like c2dm (http://code.google.com/android/c2dm/) instead to receive notifications from elsewhere. You also should refrain from defining your own URI schemes as they exist in a shared namespace. Instead you can respond to standard http URIs with a domain and path that correspond to a domain you control. If an http URI is not a good fit for what you're doing, try an "intent:" URI instead: http://goo.gl/Ka9hE

Comment: adamp makes some good points. Infact, they really should be in answer form instead of comments.